# Pandas: How to group by a datetime column, using only the time and discarding the date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a datetime column. I want to group by the time component only and aggregate, e.g. by taking the mean.

I know that I can use pd.Grouper to group by date AND time, but it doesn't work on time only.

Say we have the following dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

drange = pd.date_range('2019-08-01 00:00', '2019-08-12 12:00', freq='1T')
time = drange.time
c0 = np.random.rand(len(drange))
c1 = np.random.rand(len(drange))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(drange=drange, time=time, c0=c0, c1=c1))
print(df.head())
```

```
               drange      time        c0        c1
0 2019-08-01 00:00:00  00:00:00  0.031946  0.159739
1 2019-08-01 00:01:00  00:01:00  0.809171  0.681942
2 2019-08-01 00:02:00  00:02:00  0.036720  0.133443
3 2019-08-01 00:03:00  00:03:00  0.650522  0.409797
4 2019-08-01 00:04:00  00:04:00  0.239262  0.814565
```

In this case, the following throws a TypeError:

```py
grouper = pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='5T')
grouped = df.groupby(grouper).mean()
```

I could set `key=drange` to group by date and time and then:

- Reset the index
- Transform the new column to float
- Bin with pd.cut
- Cast back to time
- Finally group-by and then aggregate

... But I wonder whether there is a cleaner way to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Series.dt.time`/`DatetimeIndex.time` returns the time as `datetime.time`. This isn't great because pandas works best with`timedelta64` and so your `'time'` column is cast to `object`, losing all datetime functionality.

You can subtract off the normalized date to obtain the time as a `timedelta` so you can continue to use the `datetime` tools of pandas. You can `floor` this to group.

```
s = (df.drange - df.drange.dt.normalize()).dt.floor('5T')

df.groupby(s).mean()
```

---

```
                c0        c1
drange                      
00:00:00  0.436971  0.530201
00:05:00  0.441387  0.518831
00:10:00  0.465008  0.478130
...            ...       ...
23:45:00  0.523233  0.515991
23:50:00  0.468695  0.434240
23:55:00  0.569989  0.510291
```

---

Alternatively if you feel unsure of `floor`, this gets the identical output up to the index name

```
df['time'] = (df.drange - df.drange.dt.normalize())  # timedelta64[ns]
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='5T')).mean()
```

Comment: great answer! :) +1

Comment: Great Answer indeed. All the methods suggesting going to seconds and operate there are fine but they lose the value of working with dates on pandas. +1

Answer (score 0):

When you use `DataFrame.groupby` you can a [Series an argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Moreover, if your series is a datetime, you can use the `series.dt` to access the properties of date. In your case `df['drange'].dt.hour` or `df['drange'].dt.time` should do it.

```
# df['drange']=pd.to_datetime(df['drange'])
df.groupby(df['drange'].dt.hour).agg(...)
```